# Проблема с адаптивностью owl carousel - не растягивается слайды на всю ширину блока

Tags: css, jquery, owl-carousel

Есть [сайт](http://abcpack.ru/acces/), где в разделе *услуги* открываются модальные окна с [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

На разрешениях экранов ниже **1200** есть проблемы с адаптивностью: `items` почему-то не хотят растягиваться на ширину родительского `div`, либо выходят за его рамки как показано на скринах ниже.

Не могу понять в чем причина..

Вот настройки карусели:

```
$(".owl-work").owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:4000,
    dots:false,
    nav:true,
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. Первая часть с отображением на мобильных версиях решена прописыванием настройки `center: true;` Остался промежуток разрешения с 1050 до 1200

Comment: Возможно из-за модалки. Нет ли в библиотеке возможности укзаать родительсий блок для карусели?

Comment: @Za Ars поясните, что вы имеете виду под родительским? Структура у карусели всегда одинаковая, в `div` я ее оборачиваю

Comment: про родительский, я имею в виду к какому блоку он относится. В select2 были проблемы в модалке как раз по этой причине, для select2 родительский должен был быть блок модалки а не body, и я предполагаю, что здесь может быть та же проблема

Comment: Я решил вопрос с отображением на мобильных версиях подставив в настройки `center: true;` Остался промежуток разрешения с 1050 до 1200

Comment: Попробуйте во flex перевести

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.

Для **owl carusel** нельзя задавать обертку указанную в процентах, только в пикселях! Иначе, он неправильно подсчитывает ширину своих внутренних элементов. 
Задал обертке максимальную ширину на определенных разрешениях, тогда работает

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .examples-work  .owl-work img {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
}
```